# Which video player should I use?

Tags: vlc, multimedia, codecs, video-player, totem

Which video player should I use?. I watch 1080p x264 MKV (public HD), 1080p(yify).... all tipes of video. So what do you prefer? Is totem enaugh(good) Do I need install any codecs... I have clean Installation of ubuntu 14 LTS I only ticked the codecs at beginning of the installation.

Comment: This type of question is too open-ended.  If you find yourself just asking "what do you prefer", you need to do a bit more research yourself first, then come back and tell us what you've tried and what *specific* problem you found that you need to solve.
Questions which rely heavily on personal opinions are too subjective and not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I apologize for asking such question

Answer (score 2):

VLC will play all the above - **install it, it works great ;D**

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: vlc also has a lot of options. Whatever you need to do, it can. No codecs necessary.